# From Trevés - Finite order distributions in terms of Radon measures

Tags: proof-explanation, distribution-theory

Trevés, Theorem 24.4, Topological Vector Spaces, Distributions and Kernels, Dover, p. 259.

If $T$ is a distribution of finite order $\leq m$ in $\Omega$ with support $S \subset \Omega$, then given any neighbourhood $U$ of $S$ in $\Omega$, there is a family of Radon measures $\mu_p$ supported in $U$ such that $T=\sum_{|p| \leq m}(\partial/\partial x)^p \mu_p$.

The author defines $E_m=C^m_c(\Omega)$ and a map $\phi \mapsto ((\partial/\partial x)^p\phi)_{p \in \mathbb{N^n}, |p| \leq m}$ into the product $(E_0)^N$ for $\phi \in E_m$, where $N$ is the number of tuples $p=(p_1,...,p_n)$, suggests that this is an isomorphism (into), and then claims that "*we may transfer any continuous linear functional on $E_m$ as a continuous linear functional on the image of this map, and then extend the latter as a continuous linear functional on $(E_0)^N$*".

Could someone please elaborate on the authors claim and the map in question.

The statement is also given under the wiki-page ("structure of distributions of finite order" - in reference to Trevés):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_(mathematics)#Functions_as_distributions

The latter also appeared in connection with the following question on mathoverflow:

https://mathoverflow.net/questions/17732/difference-between-measures-and-distributions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $T$ has order $m$ there exists a constant $C_{U}>0$ such that
$$
|T(\phi)|\leq C_{U}\sum_{|p|\leq m}\Vert(\partial/\partial x)^{p}\phi
\Vert_{L^{\infty}(U)}%
$$
for all $\phi\in\mathcal{D}(\Omega)$ with support in $U$. In particular, by
the Hahn-Banach theorem, we can extend $T$ to a continuous linear function
$$
T:C_{c}^{m}(U)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}.
$$
Now consider the linear function
$$
L:C_{c}^{m}(U)\rightarrow C_{c}^{0}(U,\mathbb{R}^{N}),
$$
given by
$$
L(\phi)=(\phi,(\partial/\partial x)^{p_{1}}\phi,\ldots,(\partial/\partial
x)^{p_{N}}\phi),
$$
where $p_{1}, \ldots, p_{N}$ are all the multi-indeces of order between one
and $m$ (both included). Note that $L$ is injective and continuous. So
$Y=L(C_{c}^{m}(U))$ is a subspace of $C_{c}^{0}(U,\mathbb{R}^{N})$ and
$$
L:C_{c}^{m}(U)\rightarrow Y
$$
is linear, continuous, and bijective. Given $\psi\in Y$, there exists a unique
$\phi\in C_{c}^{m}(U)$ such that $L(\phi)=\psi$. Define
$$
S(\psi):=T(\phi).
$$
Then $S$ is linear, and
$$
|S(\psi)|=|T(\phi)|\leq C_{U}\sum_{i=1}^{N}\Vert(\partial/\partial x)^{p_{i}%
}\phi\Vert_{L^{\infty}(U)}=C_{U}\sum_{i=1}^{N}\Vert\psi_{i}\Vert_{L^{\infty
}(U)},
$$
which implies that $S:Y\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is linear and continuous. By the
Hahn-Banach theorem, we can extend $S$ to a linear and continuous function
$S:C_{c}^{0}(U,\mathbb{R}^{N})\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$. In turn, by the Riesz
representation theorem, we can find $N$ signed Radon measures $\mu_{i}$ such
that
$$
S(\psi)=\sum_{i=1}^{N}\int_{U}\psi_{i}\,d\mu_{i}.
$$
In particular, if $\psi=L(\phi)$, then
$$
T(\phi)=S(\psi)=\sum_{i=1}^{N}\int_{U}\psi_{i}\,d\mu_{i}=\sum_{i=1}^{N}%
\int_{U}(\partial/\partial x)^{p_{i}}\phi\,d\mu_{i}.
$$

Comment: Need to clear a few starting points. You are assuming that $T$ is compactly supported? And you are extending to where exactly? The distribution $T$ is perfectly well defined on $C^m_c(U)$ already, via transposition of the trivial extension, so why the Hahn-Banach?

Comment: You wrote that the support was $S\subset\Omega$ and you didn't specify what $S$ is, so I assumed it is compact. If it is not, I guess you need to consider first the case when youhave compact support and then use a partition of unity. Once you have the bound, you can use density to extend a distribution to $C^m_c$, so yes, no need to use Hahn- Banach. It was just faster to write!